# Implementing a "context menu" with a grid of buttons

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, uialertview

I'm wondering whether there's a better way of implementing a "context menu" in my app. This is a screenshot of how it currently looks like and as you can see, almost the entire screen is already filled up with entries:

[image]

This is actually a `UIAlertView` with multiple "other" buttons.

I wondered if it's possible to create sort of a grid layout within the alert view and add three buttons per row which show icons only, instead of labels (in order to save some space). I'd like to make it similar to this (photoshopped) layout:

[image]

I read that it's possible to create a popup with custom stuff in it by using a `UIView` but perhaps you guys know an easier trick of accomplishing the same thing with an `UIAlertView`.

Is this even possible with an alert view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's impossible to create an `UIAlertView` like this.. Create a new UIView and add it to your viewController with `[self.view addSubview:..]`

Comment: Sad to hear this but ok I'll make it with UIView then, thanks for answering! If I change to make it with an UIView is it possible to make it look like the AlertView? (with the shiny blue background)

Comment: Sure you can.. `[view setBackgroundColor:UIColor..];` you also can set a backgroundColor or a Backgroundimage for the button so it looks like an UIAlertView

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIActionSheet instead of UIAlertView in this case. Or you can use modalViewController something like this: http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/

Comment: an action sheet will also not have a grid view

Comment: then modalViewController something like this: http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/

Comment: beta: hope modalViewController will help you?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your suggestion. I will check out this post now, didn't hear of it before.

Comment: It's unfortunately not exactly what I'm after (I think). I added a picture of what I'm looking for. Might even add a bounty (in 2 days) if it's not that easy to accomplish this. As for now, many thanks for your post, though!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question; `UIActionSheet` is the HIG-approved object for the original functionality, yes, but it definitely does not provide the grid of buttons that OP wants to create.

Comment: as you can see I proposed use modalViewController. Please read my comment. I updated my answer.